# INNER JOIN with WHERE lower(...) like ... performance

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I am going to find all books which author's name like 'de%' **case-insensitive**.

I write:

```
SELECT * FROM authors a
INNER JOIN books b ON books.author_id = a.id
WHERE lower(a.first_name) like 'de%'
```

Which results in FULL TABLE ACCESS for books, with cardinality 2037700 and cost 4342.

Which is exactly the same as simple

```
SELECT * FROM books; -- Same 2037700 cardinality and 4342 cost
```

How can I tell oracle to filter books by author's id? Of course, I have index for books.author_id.

The nearest result I was able to achieve is:

```
SELECT /*+ index(b) */ * FROM books b WHERE author_id IN (SELECT id FROM authors a WHERE lower(a.first_name) like 'de%');
--gives 1028759 cardinality and 47282 cost - still not so good
```

### UPD

yes, I have two indexes for authors.first_name:

```
CREATE INDEX first_name_idx ON authors (first_name);
CREATE INDEX first_name_lower_idx ON authors (lower(first_name));
```

Execution plan says that first_name_lower_idx is **used, but cardinality** equals FULL SCAN authors.

### UPD2

Yes, no-lowercase shows much greater performance.

### UPD3

Substring doesn't make anything better.

case sensitive
[image: case sensitive]

case insensitive with functional index
[image: case insensitive with functional index]

case insensitive without index
[image: case insensitive without index]

Comment: Have you got an index `authors.first_name`?

Comment: I dont know Oracle these days but the lower function might be causing an index to be skipped.

Comment: I suspect the optimizer will filter first on a.first_name.   And use a case insensitive collation rather than lower.

Comment: curious if WHERE substr(lower(a.first_name),0,2) = 'de' would use the indexes better.

Comment: Yes I agree with above - avoid wildcard if possible

Comment: the later versions of oracle let you make a function-based index -- something like create index i1 on books(lower(first_name));  then it will use that index. yeah, otherwise if you do a function on a column it won't use the index.  Also, if you lead with a wildcard it won't use the index so like 'de%' will use an index but '%de%' won't

Comment: @Twelfth, thanks for the idea. I will try tomorrow and be back with the results.

Comment: @EdHeal, I've updated question.

Comment: @PeterM I've updated question. I got a function-based index, but it seems useless

Comment: I am not sure about cardinality, maybe that is just the # of rows it will check.  Can you post the new explain plan?  Is it now doing an index range scan?

Comment: one other thing to try, not sure if it would help, you could create an index and include the id field, that is called a covering index, then it won't have to go to the table to get the id, that might speed it up. something like create index i2 on authors (lower(last_name), id);

Comment: please see my updates

Comment: wow, yeah, I guess it thinks there are a lot of rows where the author starts with de so it is doing a hash.  Try this, no promises, put a hint in there -- right after the select type this (ignore quotes) " /*+ FIRST_ROWS */" that will maybe force it to use a nested loops join

Comment: How many records are there in Authors? How many records are there in books? How many records are fetched by your sql in total (use count to get this)?

Comment: right, good point, look at the explain plans, when you do a case sensitive search it is estimating 13 rows (cardinality) but when you do it case-insensitive it is estimating 1877 rows, that might be why it wants to do a hash join -- nested loop joins are faster for a small number of rows but at some point it becomes slower than a hash join

Answer (score 0):

Your query is much better off without using indexes. Also it seems you are missing joins. Explanation below.

Based on the cardinality reported by statistics, I assume that `Authors` table has 10431 records and `Books` table has 2037700 records.

The case sensitive predicate `WHERE cp.first_name like 'de%'` fetches only 13 records out of 10431 records from `Authors` table. And the subsequent join with `Books` table fetches only 99 rows out of 2037700 records from `Books` table. Due to a missing join or joins, you are getting (13 * 99) 1257 rows. Still, index is favoured here as the count is negligible.

The case insensitive predicate `WHERE lower(cp.first_name) like 'de%'` converts 'DE%', 'dE%' and 'De%' names also into 'de%' names. So more records will fetched from `Authors` table in the first step of the execution plan. As per the cardinality estimates from the execution plan, the case insensitive predicate is fetching all the records (10431 records) from `Authors` table. And the subsequent join with `Book` table filters into a final result set of 1028912 records. If you even force an index on `Books.author_id` using a hint, you will be hitting the index for all (10431) the `author_ids`. In this case index will only be an overhead and not a performance improvement.

Indexes are useful only in the following cases.

a. When you are fetching a small part of a big table. (**Index unique scan or Index range scan**)
b. When all the columns referred in the query are part of the index. (**Index fast full scan**).
c. When the leading index column has a low cardinality and the filters result in scan of minimum number of subtrees. (**Index skip scan**).

Also please check whether Books.authors_id has a foreign key referring to Authors.id.